# Mipmaps+PBO: strange issues

Tags: opengl, graphics

I'm using PBOs to load textures faster in my application. If I use an opengl 3 or better video card I can then easily build the mipmaps with a call to glGenerateMipmap and it works fine.
But on my older opengl 2.1 card (radeon x800), that function is not available so i must use one of two legacy methods:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP, GL_TRUE);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, w,h, 0,GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, src);
```

or

```
gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_RGBA8, w,h, GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, src);
```

The first method doesn't work fine even whitout the PBO, it introduces strange artifacts. The second one, whitout the PBO builds the correct mipmaps, and with the PBO generates a segfault.
Anyone can help??

For completeness I attach the code I use for the PBO:

```
uint pixelBuffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &pixelBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, pixelBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, size*4, NULL, GL_STATIC_READ);
char *pixels = (char*)glMapBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, GL_WRITE_ONLY);
... transfer data
glUnmapBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER);
... and then I use the buffer to create the texture
```

PS If I don't try to generate mipmaps, the pbo loading works on all my video cards.

Comment: What makes you think that using a PBO in the middle is actually faster? Read my recent explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755950/poor-opengl-image-processing-performance

Comment: Probably you should post some additional code. What `src` is initialized to in the first method?

Comment: "strange artifacts". Care to give more details ? gluBuild2D... cannot work as it is not built into GL. It's purely user-side code, that expects src to be a pointer, not an offset into a PBO.

Comment: Well, the PBO is faster because it lets me to avoid one step of client side memory allocation and copy ... with it I can directly read compressed texture data from disk and send it to the GPU memory.  Bahbar, I think you are right, probably gluBuild2DMipmaps expects a valid pointer.  The strange artifacts when using the standar method appear when opengl uses the mipmaps of level greater than zero: The level zero texture appears as it should be but when the minification filter kicks in it becomes evident that the mipmap images are totally corrupted and noisy. It looks like a driver issue.

Comment: ybungalobill: well src is initialized to NULL because I'm using the PBO and so glTexImage2D expects a NULL pointer.

Answer (score 1):

This is simple, gluBuild2DMipmaps() expects pointer in client memory (because it is just a glu function, not a part of the driver) so it will not work with PBO. As for using the

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP, GL_TRUE);

try calling it *after* glTexImage2D(). Some drivers implement this extension differently and actually require this line to be called everytime when the mipmaps should be generated (there's **nothing** done "**automatic** aly"). Your strange artifacts are actually random data in higher mipmap levels because the mipmaps weren't generated at all.

As for using PBO for speed, it is perfectly legit method. There might be a new way possible with the "pinned memory", but I haven't looked into it yet.